# Behaviour on side menu navigation between storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

Im working on my side menu navigation.

My problem is that I have 2 storyboards and I need to identify which is my current context in order to decide if I need to instantiate a new ViewController or just do a poptoRoot.

right now when I click the item in the menu it always does a new instance so when I press Logout to dismiss the parent it takes me back to the previous instance instead the Login page

I was trying to figure out in which storyboard I currently was in order to do this but the answers I find talk about using the file name which I don't really know if its either a good idea or how to fetch it ( i tried self.parent?.storyboard but found no useful properties)

this is what i've already tried

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

var topVc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController;

if (self.parent is MasterViewController)
{
    parent.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    return
}

if (topVc?.restorationClass == MasterViewController.self)
{

    parent.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    return
}

if (topVc?.restorationIdentifier == "MyMeetings")
{
    parent.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    return
}

if ( topVc?.isKind(of: MasterViewController.self ))!
{
    parent.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    return
}

let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyMeetings") as UIViewController

parent.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: MyMeetings is the navigation controller of MasterViewController

Comment: I did solve the logout problem by using self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) . instead parent.dismiss but I still need to fix the problem of creating multiple instances when navigating in the menu

Comment: I now made the view controllers singletons and start getting Application tried to present modally an active controller MasterViewController